# CSS issue: How to align <div> elements (<div>, header, footer, and body) vertically with responsive web design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, alignment, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align the header, body, footer, and div's vertically in one column such that the web design is responsive (looks good on different screen sizes): ConfluenceInfinite.org  or see dev subdomain below.

For people who are new to `html` and `css` (like me) this is a pure `css`/`html` implementation/markup including the menu.

[image: Image from a cell phone screen capture.]

[image: Same issue as above, but screenshot is from a computer and illustrates the issue in the footer area.]

You can go to my development subdomain to see the issue first-hand:
[my development subdomain: dev.confluenceinfinite.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZFrtm.png)

I have done LOT of research on this. Here is some of that research:

I don't believe this question/answer applies to my issue because my issue is vertical alignment (correct me if I am wrong). It uses fixed `px` values, which won't work for cell phones, and I tried the `display: inline-block`, but it didn't work. Here is the link to the SO question:
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334657/how-to-align-div-elements)

This question/answer (which got via searching OS tag vertical-alignment) also has a fixed width that I do not want to do because I want the `<div>`s to be fully dynamic for all screen sizes:  [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom/585965#585965)

I don't think this helps either because it aligns elements within a container, but I want the containers/div's aligned. Am I missing something?:
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div)

This solution has the correct title/heading, but aligns things on the "right" vertically, which don't seem applicable to my issue:
 [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302036/align-div-elements-vertically)

I used to use a website or program that allowed a developer to test/visualize website design on multiple screen sizes. I can no longer find that site. If you know the location of that site, please comment or put it in your answer. Thanks!

Here is my index/home page `html` markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <link rel="icon" type="/images/png" href="/images/CII - favicon for website - 2020-09-17 0435.png" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/StylePage.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/StyleMenu.css" />
    <title>CII - Optimizing change for the benefit of all.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <!-- start ============================================================================ menu (goes in header) ============================== start -->
      <div class="menu-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggler" />
        <div class="hamburger">
          <div class="ClassForTidy"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <div>
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="Index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="Team.html">Team</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="Definitions.html">Definitions</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="HaveDoubts.html">Have Doubts?</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="DonateToday.html">Donate Today</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="GetInvolved.html">Get Involved</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="TheMovement.html">The Movement</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="c11.html">c11</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="TheCeosStory.html">The CEO's Story</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="News.html">News</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end ============================================================================ menu (goes in header) ============================== end -->
      <!-- start ============================================================================ header text ============================== start -->
      <p id="HeaderText">-------------------- SITE UNDER CONSTRUCTION -------------------- this is a test to see if the right side of this text is dropping off the page or not it has to be very long to test the issue</p>
      <!-- end ============================================================================ header text ============================== end -->
    </header>
    <div class="site-wrap">
      <!-- start ============================================================================ logo region ============================== start -->
      <figure class="fig_logo_reg">
        <img src="/images/CII_Logo.PNG" class="img_logo_reg" />
      </figure>
      <!-- end ============================================================================ logo region ============================== end -->
      <!-- start ============================================================================ start page content ============================== start -->
        <!-- start ============================================================================ paste content below ============================== start -->
        <div class="container showcase-inner">
          <br />
          <br />
          <h1 style="font-size:30px; color: black; padding: 10px 0 0 0; margin: 30px 0; line-height: 30px;">Why doesn't the system favor "the good guy"? Let's rig the system in your
          favor.</h1>
          <h1 style="font-size:30px; color: black; padding: 10px 0 0 0; margin: 30px 0; line-height: 30px;">We know how to fund the "unicorn" and tame the "machine" whilst compelling
          people to change how they think, work, and have fun so it benefits good people, without breaking any laws. Truly.</h1>
          <br />
          <p>The world is focused on money, getting people’s attention, and offering goods and service at an equilibrium price
          where both the lowest financial cost and highest financial gain are at. CII is focused on destroying this “machine”
          and system of values in a legal, ethical, and morally sound way. CII has created technology that will facilitate,
          perpetuate, and maintain the new system by optimizing change for the benefit of all that will connect good people,
          produce optimal “humanitarian value” output, and simultaneously destroy the old system over time. CII will facilitate
          this with the help of good people in a way that will protect individuals and their livelihood achieving a better system
          for society.</p>
          <a href="AboutUs.html" class="btn">Read More this is a test to see if the right side of this text is dropping off the page or not it has to be very long to test the issue</a>
        </div>
        <!-- end ============================================================================  paste content above  ============================== end -->
      </div>
    <!-- start =============================================================== footer ============================================= end -->
    <footer>
    <div class="navLeftFooter nav-globe" id="navFooter">
      <a href="#top" id="navBackToTop">
        <div class="navFooterBackToTop">
          <span class="navFooterBackToTopText">Go Back to Top of Page - this is a test to see if the right side of this text is dropping off the page or not it has to be very long to test the issue</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="navFooterVerticalColumn navAccessibility" role="presentation">
        <div class="navFooterVerticalRow navAccessibility" style="display: table-row;">
          <div class="navFooterLinkCol navAccessibility">
            <div class="navFooterColHead">Get to Know Us</div>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav_first">
                <a href="GetInvolved.html" class="nav_a">Careers &amp; Volunteer</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="TheCeosStory.html" class="nav_a">Blog</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="AboutUs.html" class="nav_a">About CII</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="AboutUs.html#TargetSusCsr" class="nav_a">Sustainability</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="News.html" class="nav_a">News &amp; Press Center</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Donor Relations</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="navFooterColSpacerInner navAccessibility"></div>
          <div class="navFooterLinkCol navAccessibility">
            <div class="navFooterColHead">Get Involved with CII's Platform</div>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav_first">
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Become an Affiliate</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Become a Strategic Partner</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Offer Your Product or Service/"Advertise"</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Submit an Ideology for Consideration</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Submit an Idea for Consideration</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Submit a Core Value for Consideration</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Submit a Concept for Consideration</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Submit a Core Change for Consideration</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Submit Anything Else</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="navFooterColSpacerInner navAccessibility"></div>
          <div class="navFooterLinkCol navAccessibility">
            <div class="navFooterColHead">Connect with People</div>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav_first">
                <a href="TheMovement.html" class="nav_a">The Movement</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="c11.html" class="nav_a">c11</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">CII</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="navFooterColSpacerInner navAccessibility"></div>
          <div class="navFooterLinkCol navAccessibility">
            <div class="navFooterColHead">Help People</div>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav_first">
                <a href="c11.html" class="nav_a">c11 - this is a test to see if the right side of this text is dropping off the page or not it has to be very long to test the issue</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Report Something</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Pay Something Forward</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Report a "Do-gooder"</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Report a High Humanitarian Value Output Organization</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Report a High Humanitarian Value Output Business</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Report a High Humanitarian Value Output nonprofit</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Report a High Humanitarian Value Output Government/Country</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav_last">
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Help</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-footer-line"></div>
      <div class="navFooterLine navFooterLinkLine navFooterPadItemLine">
        <div class="navFooterLine navFooterLogoLine">
          <figure id="FigLogoTiny">
            <img src="/images/CII%20-%20favicon%20for%20website%20-%202020-09-17%200435.png" />
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="navFooterLine"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- end ============================================================================ footer ============================== end -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the `style.css`:

```
/* imports see https://medium.com/@elad/normalize-css-or-css-reset-9d75175c5d1e#_=_    */
@import "resets/normalize.css";
@import "resets/reset.local.css";
@import "resets/typography.css";

/* CORE STYLES */
:root {
  --primary-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  --overlay-color: rgba(24, 39, 51 , 0.85);
  --menu-speed: 0.75s;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

header {

    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.38, 0.9);
    background: var(--cds-ui-background, #fff);
    border: none;
    max-width: 100vw; /*99rem;*/
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5999;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 3rem;
    background-color: #161616;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

#HeaderText {
        margin-bottom: auto;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        color: white;
        padding-top: 12px;
}

#SharePopup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60px;
  /* height: 60px; */
  padding: 1rem;
  /* background: var(--primary-color); */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  height: 3rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #06D85F;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    
}
#SharePopup:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

h1 {
        line-height: 35px;
        font-size: 23px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        padding-top: 15px;
        text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}
.container {
  max-width: 100vw;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /*removed on 2020-09-28 to get text to spread accross screen more and not be so scrunched/narrow in the div/tall etc*/
  /* padding: 0 3rem; */
}

.showcase {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.showcase:before {
  content: '';
  /* background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/533923/pexels-photo-533923.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260') no-repeat center center/cover;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -1;
}

.showcase .showcase-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80%;
}

.showcase h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding: 15px;
}

.showcase p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: black;
}

.site-wrap {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* background-color: #ffffff; /* white */ 
  /* position: relative; */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 4em; /*spaces out content from hamburger*/
}

.site-wrap img {
    max-width: 100vw; /*60% */
    max-height: 45vh; /*60% */
    display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.site-wrap p {
        padding: 5px;
}
.site-wrap figure {
    align-items: center;
}
.site-wrap ul
        , li {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px; 
    padding-left: 15px;
}


.container.showcase-inner .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: white; /*var(--secondary-color);*/
  color: black;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
   border:1px solid black;
   border-radius: 25px;
   
   /*fixmeben*/
    text-align: center;
   display: block;
   
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  background: gray;
}

/* footer stuff */

#navFooter.navLeftFooter .navFooterBackToTop .navFooterBackToTopText {
    color: white;
}
#navFooter .navFooterBackToTop span {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #111;
    padding: 15px 0;
    line-height: 19px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#navFooter a, #navFooter span {
    font-family: inherit;
    white-space: normal;
}

#navFooter a:link, #navFooter a:visited {
    font-family: inherit;
    color: #004B91;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a, a:active, a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0066c0;
}
user agent stylesheet
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.a-ember body {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
}
body {
    color: #0F1111;
}
body {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 19px;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
}
html {
    font-size: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
#navFooter.navLeftFooter .navFooterBackToTop {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: gray;
}
#navFooter .navFooterBackToTop {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
/* * { */
    /* -moz-box-sizing: border-box; */
    /* -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; */
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
/* } */
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}
#navFooter a:link, #navFooter a:visited {
    font-family: inherit;
    color: #004B91;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navFooter a, #navFooter span {
    font-family: inherit;
    white-space: normal;
}
a, a:active, a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0066c0;
}
user agent stylesheet
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* body { */
    /* color: #0F1111; */
/* } */
/* body { */
    /* font-size: 13px; */
    /* line-height: 19px; */
    /* font-family: Arial,sans-serif; */
/* } */
/* html { */
    /* font-size: 100%; */
    /* -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; */
/* } */
 /* start footer table 1 starting with Get to know us */

#navFooter .navAccessibility.navFooterVerticalColumn {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#navFooter.navLeftFooter .navFooterVerticalColumn {
    /* changed 2020-09-28 18:10 */
    max-width: 100vw;
    background: rgb(105,105,105);
}
#navFooter .navAccessibility.navFooterVerticalRow {
    display: table-row;
}
#navFooter .navAccessibility.navFooterLinkCol {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#navFooter .navAccessibility.navFooterLinkCol {
    line-height: 120%;
}

.navFooterLinkCol {
    color: #333;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#navFooter.navLeftFooter .navFooterColHead {
    font-weight: 700;
}
.navFooterColHead {
    font-family: inherit;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 6px 0 14px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.navFooterLinkCol ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.a-ordered-list, .a-unordered-list, ol, ul {
    padding: 0;
}
.a-unordered-list, ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 18px;
    color: #111;
}
#navFooter.navLeftFooter .navFooterLinkCol ul li {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.navFooterLinkCol ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}

.a-ordered-list li, .a-unordered-list li, ol li, ul li {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.a-unordered-list li, ul li {
    list-style: disc;
}
li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

.a-unordered-list, ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 18px;
    color: #111;
}

#navFooter .navAccessibility.navFooterLinkCol {
    line-height: 120%;
}
.navFooterLinkCol {
    color: #333;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#navFooter.navLeftFooter a.nav_a:link, #navFooter.navLeftFooter a.nav_a:visited, #navFooter.navLeftFooter li.nav_a_carat span.nav_a_carat {
    color: #DDD;
}
#navFooter a:link, #navFooter a:visited {
    font-family: inherit;
    color: #004B91;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navFooter a, #navFooter span {
    font-family: inherit;
    white-space: normal;
}
a, a:active, a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0066c0;
}

/* working on navFooterColSpacerInner */
#navFooter .navAccessibility.navFooterColSpacerInner, #navFooter .navAccessibility.navFooterLinkCol {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.navFooterVerticalColumn .navFooterColSpacerInner {
    width: 5%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
#navFooter.navLeftFooter .nav-footer-line {
    border-top: 1px solid #3a4553;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#navFooter.navLeftFooter div.navFooterLine {
/* working */   
    max-width: 25%;
}
#navFooter.navLeftFooter .navFooterLinkLine {
    margin: 10px auto;
}
#navFooter.navLeftFooter .navFooterLogoLine, #navFooter.navLeftFooter .navFooterPadItemLine {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100vw;
    margin: 30px auto 15px;
}
div.navFooterLine {
    font-family: inherit;
    color: #767676;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.navFooterLinkLine {
    margin: 0 8px 0 8px;
}
#navFooter a, #navFooter span {
    font-family: inherit;
    white-space: normal;
}
.navFooterPadItemLine a, .navFooterPadItemLine span {
    padding: 0 .6em;
}
.navFooterLinkLine span, .navFooterLinkLine ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#navFooter.navLeftFooter div.navFooterLine {
    font-size: 12px;
}
#navFooter.navLeftFooter .navFooterLogoLine, #navFooter.navLeftFooter .navFooterPadItemLine {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100vw;
    margin: 30px auto 15px;
}
div.navFooterLogoLine {
    margin: 30px 8px 4px 8px;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0;
}
div.navFooterLine {
    font-family: inherit;
    color: #767676;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
a, a:active, a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0066c0;
}
#navFooter .nav-logo-base {
    background-position: -10px -90px;
    width: 76px;
    height: 23px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url('/images/CII_Logo.png');
}
.nav-globe .nav-globe, .nav-globe .nav-icon {
    
    /* background-color: black;  */
}

#FigLogoTiny {
    /*working*/
    /* max-width: 5%; */
    max-height: 5%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* bottom: 100%; */
    /* right: 100%; */
    
}
```

I am happy to include the `import`s if that is helpful. I assume you can see that by inspecting the website directly, but I am happy to edit this question to include the `import` `css`. Trying to keep the question as organized and short as possible.

I will be watching this question to see if anyone needs anything further to answer it or provide any assistance at all. I will edit the question as soon as possible if necessary. Thanks!

PS - I'm trying to make the solution/my website work across all browsers and all screen sizes without any scripts, if that is possible.

PSS - On a computer you have to size the window down to see the issue...that's what I did in the computer screenshot above to illustrate the issue.

EDIT-1: I should also state that the preferable responsiveness/dynamic/movement/etc. for the footer is to have a `div` column slide down below the other `div` columns if it doesn't fully fit on the page/isn't all visible to the user.

Comment: I think the proper expression you are looking for is 'responsive webdesign', you want your page to fit 'snugly' on both a mobile and a desktop. Vertical alignment of elements is just one of several constructions needed to make that work. Have a look at my pen at Codepen [Example for MadBoy](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/wvGXBGy?editors=1000) showing a vanilla CSS solution for a *card list* that works for all kinds of devices. It uses CSS *Flexbox Layout* for positioning, some *linear equations* for sizing and font scaling. Obviously not your site, but its quite easy to understand...

Comment: And, as I usually do, most code is properly comment, so it should be rather self-explanatory. Copy the code into a new document and open it (outside Codepen) in a browser and start resizing the browser window to see what happens. Feel free to ask more or enter SO chat....

Comment: Through SO Chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com and you have to invite someone to a room. It's the worst to access, but better than nothing at all. I always have to search 'help' to figure out how to get it going...

Comment: @RenevanderLende - The answer Pine Code provided worked for the `img`, so I'm going with that. I'm taking a look at your "cards" example for the footer only and I'm not sure where to start. I'll send you chat if I need more help. Feel free to post an answer if you have time :) either way, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest example I found to solve the footer issue. This allows the footer divs to come down and create a new row as the screen is resized. Its a bit over simplified, but easy to understand. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: Blue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>

<p>text - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

...it is a slight modification of this example:
[Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_nowrap8)

Rene van der Lende's comment contains the code I ended up using to solve the same issue as the code above (the footer) but with a more professional look...sort of. It has a bit more eye candy/more professional look, but is much more complex to understand for a beginner: [Click Here](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/wvGXBGy?editors=1000)

Here is the code from the link above, but you can see it in action in the link above:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1">

<title>Example for MadBoy</title>

<style id="ers-globals-default">
/**************************/
/* preferred global rules */
/**************************/
html,body               { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 100% }
*::before,*::after, *   { box-sizing: inherit }
body                    { margin: 0 }

/* responsive base font size using y = mx + b */
html   { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) } /* (320,14)(1280,20) */

/***************************************/
/* responsive FLEXBOX bands and blocks */
/***************************************/
/*
    For use as easy 'landingpage' content containers
    [band]  - horizontal content like a strip
    [block] - vertical content like a list

    - Can both be used interchangeably and nested
      (band of blocks, block of bands, band of blocks holding bands of...)
    - Invert orientation with 'rows'/'cols' parameter ( *= means: contains )
*/
[band],[block]          { display: flex; position: relative; overflow: hidden }
[band],[block]          { justify-content: center; align-content: center }

[band],[band*="cols"]   { flex-flow: row wrap    }  /* a row of columns, default */
       [band*="rows"]   { flex-flow: column wrap }  /* a column of rows */

[block],[block*="rows"] { flex-flow: column wrap }  /* inverse default of [band] */
        [block*="cols"] { flex-flow: row wrap    }

.padded,
[padded="1"],
[padded="0"] [band*="padded"],
[padded="0"] [block*="padded"] {
/*
    responsive page padding using y = mx + b
    and responsive band/block padding (same as responsive page padding, but at band/block level)
    p1(320,32) p2(1920, 72) => 0.025x + 24
    p3(320, 8) p4(1920,320) => 0.195x - 54.4 

    'band/block padding' is only active when 'page padding' is off 
*/
    padding: calc( 2.5vh + 24px) calc(19.5vw - 54.4px);
}
</style>
<style id="stl-cards-default">
/****************/
/* FLEXBOX Card */
/****************/
/* Everything card related is FBL */
[band*="cards"]>*,
[card],[card]>* { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap }

/* generic 'band' holding 1:N cards */
[band*="cards"]>* {
    flex-basis: auto; /* Workaround, see comment below */   
    /* default width (4 to 6 vp columns, depends on [band] L/R padding) */
    width: calc(1.9375vw + 277.8px); /* (320,284)(1920,315) */

/*
    The preferred rule is flex-basis: calc(1.9375vw + 277.8px), without 'width' defined,
    but I use border-box box model throughout this demo (and anywhere else b.t.w.), so: 
    
    from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis

    "When a non-auto flex-basis is specified, Internet Explorer 10 and 11 
     always use a content-box box model to calculate the size of a flex item,
     even if 'box-sizing: border-box' is applied to the element. See Flexbug #7 for more info."

    Flexbug #7, https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#7-flex-basis-doesnt-account-for-box-sizingborder-box
    See Flexbug #8 too, why 'flex-grow: 1' has to used for IE11 instead of 'flex: 1'
*/
    flex-grow : 1;                  /* set to 0 for non-stretching cards */
/*    align-self: flex-start;         /* 'stretch' is preferred as 'flex-start' yields jagged heights */
}
/* TODO: maybe introduce  W/H dependency with MQ 'orientation' */

[card] {
    flex-direction: column;         /* VERTICAL container of header,content,footer */
    justify-content: space-between; /* moves header/footer to top/bottom of card */
    width: 100%; height: 100%;      /* for IE11 */
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

[card]>* { width: 100%; max-width: 100% } /* All card main rows: fill-width */

[card]>item {
    flex-direction: column;         /* COLUMN of 1:N rows */
    flex-grow: 1;                   /* card content, fill max available space */
    overflow: auto;                 /* scroll content in case card max-height set */

}
</style>
<style id="stl-card-demo">
/*******************************************/
/* [OPTIONAL] Card eye-candy and animation */
/*******************************************/
[band*="header"],
[band*="cards"] { background-color: rgba( 75, 84,104,.6);color: rgba(255,255,255,.8) }

[band*="cards"]>* { /* 'height' must have VW too, otherwise ratios will be incorrect */
/*    height    : calc((1.9375vw + 277.8px) * 1.77778);   /* Fixed W/H ratio 16:9 */
/*    max-height: calc((1.9375vw + 277.8px) * 1.77778);
    /* Adjust 'max-height' to choosen ratio or 0 in case of 'auto' (or remove) */

    cursor: pointer; /* It's animated, ok? So, no...clicker-de-click */
    -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none
}

[card]>header { justify-content: center   }
[card]>footer { justify-content: flex-end }

/*
    minimal padding around cards, but only if not already padded
    (nasty little trick with selector preference => [padded] will not work here
    because of same preference as [band])
*/
[band*="cards"]:not(.padded),
[band*="cards"]>*     { padding: calc(0.125vmin + 1.6px)} /* 2,4>1920 */
[card] > :not(.media) { padding: calc(0.5vmin + 14.4px) } /* 16,24>1920 */

[card] {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);  /* white */
    color: rgba( 89, 89, 89,1);             /* Davy's Grey */

    opacity: .95; /* for a subtle color diffence on :hover */

    /* Google Material Components Web default card elevation */
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.20),
                0px 1px 1px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0px 1px 3px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.12); /* elevation 1dp */
}
[card]:hover {
    opacity: 1; /* ditto */

    box-shadow: 0px 3px  5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.20),
                0px 5px  8px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0px 1px 14px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.12); /* elevation 5dp */
}
[card]:active,
[card]:focus { transform: scale(0.995) }
</style>

<style id="ers-utility-default">
/**************************************************/
/* Utility rules, first so they can be overridden */
/**************************************************/
body  { cursor: default } /* Plain arrow for everything, but... */
input { cursor: auto    } /* ...use HTML default cursor on inputs, unless it is an: */

input[list="datalist"],input[type="button"],input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"],
input[type="color"],input[type="range"],input[type="reset"],input[type="file"],input[type="submit"],
label:not([for=""]),
a,button,select,keygen   { cursor: pointer } 
[contenteditable="true"] { cursor: text    }

/* Darker/more contrast text (put in <body>)
   => GPU intensive, set default to "0" if document scroll feels too sluggish. */
[cleartype="1"]         { text-shadow: .1px  .1px .2px hsla(0,0%,15%,.35),
                                      -.1px -.1px .2px hsla(0,0%,15%,.25) }
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,b,
[cleartype="0"],strong  { text-shadow: none } /* exceptions, no need to go even 'bolder' */

/* prohibit user from selecting text (put in <body>) */
.noselect,[select="0"],[noselect] { -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none }
.select  ,[select="1"],[select]   { -webkit-user-select: text; -moz-user-select: text; -ms-user-select: text; user-select: text }
/* enable user to select text (put in specific elements) */

[push*="R"] { margin-left  : auto } /* push elements Right/Left/Top/Bottom */
[push*="L"] { margin-right : auto }
[push*="T"] { margin-top   : auto }
[push*="B"] { margin-bottom: auto }

[align*="C"] { text-align: center  } /* text alignment */
[align*="J"] { text-align: justify }
[align*="L"] { text-align: left    }
[align*="R"] { text-align: right   }

[hide], [data-hide="1"] {
    display: none; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    z-index: -999999; top: -999999px; margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0;
    height: 1px; width: 1px; min-height: 0; min-width: 0; max-height: 0; max-width: 0
}

::-moz-focus-inner { padding: 0; border: 0 } /* Firefox */
:focus { outline: dotted rgba(60,69,78,.5) 2px }
:focus { outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0; outline-width: 0 } /* for Edge 2020 */

/* show all elements with outlines (put in <body>) */
[outlines="1"] * { outline: 1px dashed }
</style>

</head>
<body padded="0" cleartype="0" outlines="0">
<div block>
    <header band="header">
        <h1>headline</h1>
    </header>
    <article band="list.cards" class="padded">
        <div>
            <div card>
               <img class="media" src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x240">
                <header><h3>interactive SVG</h3></header>
                <item>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et
                        deleniti copiosae.</p>
                </item>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div card>
               <img class="media" src="https://picsum.photos/320/240?random=1">
                <header><h3>subline</h3></header>
                <item>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et
                        deleniti copiosae.</p>
                </item>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div card>
               <img class="media" src="https://picsum.photos/320/240?random=2">
                <header><h3>subline</h3></header>
                <item>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et
                        deleniti copiosae.</p>
                </item>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div card>
               <img class="media" src="https://picsum.photos/320/240?random=3">
                <header><h3>subline</h3></header>
                <item>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et
                        deleniti copiosae.</p>
                </item>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div card>
               <img class="media" src="https://picsum.photos/320/240?random=4">
                <header><h3>subline</h3></header>
                <item>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et
                        deleniti copiosae.</p>
                </item>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div card>
               <img class="media" src="https://picsum.photos/320/240?random=5">
                <header><h3>subline</h3></header>
                <item>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et
                        deleniti copiosae.</p>
                </item>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div card>
               <img class="media" src="https://picsum.photos/320/240?random=6">
                <header><h3>subline</h3></header>
                <item>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et
                        deleniti copiosae.</p>
                </item>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div card>
               <img class="media" src="https://picsum.photos/320/240?random=7">
                <header><h3>subline</h3></header>
                <item>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et
                        deleniti copiosae.</p>
                </item>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div card>
               <img class="media" src="https://picsum.photos/320/240?random=8">
                <header><h3>subline</h3></header>
                <item>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et
                        deleniti copiosae.</p>
                </item>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div card>
               <img class="media" src="https://picsum.photos/320/240?random=9">
                <header><h3>subline</h3></header>
                <item>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et
                        deleniti copiosae.</p>
                </item>
                <footer>footer</footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

...please post a simpler solution that can be applied directly to my original question/code (not a simplified one) and I'll mark your answer as correct. Until then I think this is the best answer.

Pine Code answered the logo/header/image issue:

Replace:

```
.site-wrap img {
    max-width: 100vw;
    ...
}
```

...with:

```
.site-wrap img {
    max-width: 100%;
    ...
}
```

Thanks Pine code.

EDIT 1: Here is the code I actually ended up using for the footer, which was the difficult part. I ended up using the w3schools.com example mentioned above with some modifications, namely changing `nowrap` to `wrap`:

HTML:

```
<!-- start =============================================================== footer ============================================= end -->
    <footer>
      <div class="navLeftFooter nav-globe" id="navFooter">
        <a href="#top" id="navBackToTop">
          <div class="navFooterBackToTop">
            <span class="navFooterBackToTopText">Go Back to Top of Page</span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="navFooterLine navFooterLinkLine navFooterPadItemLine">
          <div class="navFooterLine navFooterLogoLine">
            <figure id="FigLogoTiny">
              <img src="/images/CII%20-%20favicon%20for%20website%20-%202020-09-17%200435.png" />
            </figure>
          </div>
          <div class="navFooterLine"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- ========================================================================== footer lists - begin ===================================================================  -->
        <div class="flex-container">
          <div>
            <p class="navFooterColHead">Get Involved with CII's Platform</p>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav_first">
                <a href="TheMovement.html" class="nav_a">The Movement</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="c11.html" class="nav_a">c11</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">CII</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Report Something</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Pay Something Forward</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Report a "Do-gooder"</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Report a High Humanitarian Value Output Organization</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Report a High Humanitarian Value Output Business</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Report a High Humanitarian Value Output nonprofit</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Report a High Humanitarian Value Output Government/Country</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav_last">
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Help</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="navFooterColHead">Get to Know Us</p>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav_first">
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Become an Affiliate</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Become a Strategic Partner</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Offer Your Product or Service/"Advertise"</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Submit an Ideology for Consideration</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Submit an Idea for Consideration</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Submit a Core Value for Consideration</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Submit a Concept for Consideration</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Submit a Core Change for Consideration</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Submit Anything Else</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="Tactics.html" class="nav_a">Tactical Strategy</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="navFooterColHead">Help Others</p>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav_first">
                <a href="GetInvolved.html" class="nav_a">Careers &amp; Volunteering</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="TheCeosStory.html" class="nav_a">Blog</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="AboutUs.html" class="nav_a">About CII</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="AboutUs.html#TargetSusCsr" class="nav_a">Sustainability</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="News.html" class="nav_a">News &amp; Press Center</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="ContactUs.html" class="nav_a">Donor Relations</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- <div>4</div> -->
          <!-- <div>5</div> -->
          <!-- <div>6</div> -->
          <!-- <div>7</div> -->
          <!-- <div>8</div> -->
        </div>
        <div class="nav-footer-line"></div>
        <p style="text-align: center; color: white; background-color: black;">© 2020, Confluence Infinite International NPO or its
        affiliates</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

CSS:

(My css is so overly complex right now I hit the SO character limit, so I only included the most critical part. For full css chat me or go to: confluenceinfinite.org and do an right-click > inspect.)

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: Gray;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 427px;
  margin: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

 /* float: left; */
}

.flex-container > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.flex-container > div > a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really appreciate the focus and politeness of your question. I’ve barely seen something like that. As for the issue, I split it in two parts, one for the image and one for the footer. Responsive Web Design is definitely what you’re looking for. As for the image, replace

```
.site-wrap img {
    max-width: 100vw;
    ...
}
```

with

```
.site-wrap img {
    max-width: 100%;
    ...
}
```

As for the footer, things get a little bit more complicated, so I show a simple example of what you can do:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
p { flex: 1; }
#one { background: red; }
#two { background: pink; }
#three { background: green; }

div { display: flex; flex-direction: row; }

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  div { flex-direction: column; }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="one">
    First
  </p>
  <p id="two">
    Second
  </p>
  <p id="three">
    Third
  </p>
</div>
```

If you open this page full size and resize the viewport of the browser, you can see how the elements are placed vertically to make the most out of the available space.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this: `.site-wrap img {
 max-width: 100%; 
 max-height: 45vh; 
 display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

footer {
 display: flex; 
 flex-direction: row;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  footer { flex-direction: column; }
}

footer > a {
 flex: 1;
}`  And it didn't seem to work. I don't have `<p>`s in the footer so I guessed. Is that the best way to do that? I'm trying to get the footer div columns to move down and to the left if they don't fully fit on the screen. I will add that to the question now. My bad. However, the `img` css worked!

Comment: `<p>...</p>` was just an example. You can use whatever element you want. If your footer is made up of `div` elements, use them. The `img` worked because you specified `100vw`, but the size of the container of the image could not be the same as the size of the viewport (just think about adding margins or paddings). I highly recommend you try Flexbox with your `div` elements; let me know if this works for you!